# Sort Array Alphabetically and Numerically in Year to Value Pairs

Tags: php, arrays

Am looking over the PHP manual on [Array Sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) but cannot seem to get this in the proper order.

Basically in my PHP script I'm getting an array of Year Make Models and Engines, and then using `array_unique` to get only the unique Year Make and Models.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2012 Jeep Liberty
    [7] => 2011 Jeep Liberty
    [12] => 2010 Jeep Liberty
    [15] => 2009 Jeep Liberty
    [18] => 2008 Jeep Liberty
    [22] => 2007 Jeep Liberty
    [26] => 2006 Jeep Liberty
    [33] => 2006 Jeep Wrangler
    [44] => 2005 Jeep Liberty
    [51] => 2005 Jeep Wrangler
    [60] => 2004 Jeep Liberty
    [64] => 2004 Jeep Wrangler
    [73] => 2003 Jeep Liberty
    [77] => 2003 Jeep Wrangler
    [86] => 2002 Jeep Liberty
    [92] => 2002 Jeep Wrangler
    [96] => 2001 Jeep Cherokee
    [102] => 2001 Jeep Wrangler
    [106] => 2000 Jeep Cherokee
    [114] => 2000 Jeep Wrangler
    [117] => 1999 Jeep Cherokee
    [125] => 1999 Jeep Wrangler
    [128] => 1998 Jeep Cherokee
    [136] => 1998 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [149] => 1998 Jeep Wrangler
    [152] => 1997 Jeep Cherokee
    [159] => 1997 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [169] => 1997 Jeep Wrangler
    [173] => 1996 Jeep Cherokee
    [181] => 1996 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [186] => 1995 Jeep Cherokee
    [193] => 1995 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [203] => 1995 Jeep Wrangler
)
```

What I'm trying to do is sort the array so, not only the years match up, but also the Make and Model. Something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2012 Jeep Liberty
    [7] => 2011 Jeep Liberty
    [12] => 2010 Jeep Liberty
    [15] => 2009 Jeep Liberty
    [18] => 2008 Jeep Liberty
    [22] => 2007 Jeep Liberty
    [26] => 2006 Jeep Liberty
    [44] => 2005 Jeep Liberty
    [60] => 2004 Jeep Liberty
    [73] => 2003 Jeep Liberty
    [86] => 2002 Jeep Liberty
    [33] => 2006 Jeep Wrangler
    [51] => 2005 Jeep Wrangler
    [64] => 2004 Jeep Wrangler
    [77] => 2003 Jeep Wrangler
    [92] => 2002 Jeep Wrangler
    [102] => 2001 Jeep Wrangler 
    [114] => 2000 Jeep Wrangler
    [125] => 1999 Jeep Wrangler
    [149] => 1998 Jeep Wrangler
    [169] => 1997 Jeep Wrangler
    [203] => 1995 Jeep Wrangler
    [96] => 2001 Jeep Cherokee
    [106] => 2000 Jeep Cherokee
    [117] => 1999 Jeep Cherokee
    [128] => 1998 Jeep Cherokee
    [152] => 1997 Jeep Cherokee
    [173] => 1996 Jeep Cherokee
    [186] => 1995 Jeep Cherokee
    [136] => 1998 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [159] => 1997 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [181] => 1996 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [193] => 1995 Jeep Grand Cherokee
)
```

Or something of that nature (sorted this manually, I will probably do a [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on the array to re-index the keys) -- I just want the Years and the Make/Models to be sorted properly.

What is my best option here?

Comment: `I'm getting an array of Year Make Models and Engines` Where are you getting this array? It might be easier to sort it where you get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort first the Maker and Model, you can make something like this (assuming the years always have four digits):

```
<?php
usort(
    $array,
    function ($value1, $value2) {
        $parts1 = explode(' ', $value1, 2);
        $parts2 = explode(' ', $value2, 2);
        return strcasecmp(
            "$parts1[1] $parts1[0]",
            "$parts2[1] $parts2[0]"
        );
    }
);
print_r($array);
```

The trick was to rearrange the strings when comparing the order, for instance, "Jeep Cherokee 1995".

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1995 Jeep Cherokee
    [1] => 1996 Jeep Cherokee
    [2] => 1997 Jeep Cherokee
    [3] => 1998 Jeep Cherokee
    [4] => 1999 Jeep Cherokee
    [5] => 2000 Jeep Cherokee
    [6] => 2001 Jeep Cherokee
    [7] => 1995 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [8] => 1996 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [9] => 1997 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [10] => 1998 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [11] => 2002 Jeep Liberty
    [12] => 2003 Jeep Liberty
    [13] => 2004 Jeep Liberty
    [14] => 2005 Jeep Liberty
    [15] => 2006 Jeep Liberty
    [16] => 2007 Jeep Liberty
    [17] => 2008 Jeep Liberty
    [18] => 2009 Jeep Liberty
    [19] => 2010 Jeep Liberty
    [20] => 2011 Jeep Liberty
    [21] => 2012 Jeep Liberty
    [22] => 1995 Jeep Wrangler
    [23] => 1997 Jeep Wrangler
    [24] => 1998 Jeep Wrangler
    [25] => 1999 Jeep Wrangler
    [26] => 2000 Jeep Wrangler
    [27] => 2001 Jeep Wrangler
    [28] => 2002 Jeep Wrangler
    [29] => 2003 Jeep Wrangler
    [30] => 2004 Jeep Wrangler
    [31] => 2005 Jeep Wrangler
    [32] => 2006 Jeep Wrangler
)
```

Here's another solution (without the previous assumption):

```
<?php
$enginesYears = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $value, 2);
    $year = (int)$parts[0];
    $engine = $parts[1];
    if (!isset($enginesYears[$engine])) {
        $enginesYears[$engine] = array();
    }
    $enginesYears[$engine][] = $year;
}
ksort($enginesYears);
$array = array();
foreach ($enginesYears as $engine => $years) {
    rsort($years);
    foreach ($years as $year) {
        $array[] = "$year $engine";
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2001 Jeep Cherokee
    [1] => 2000 Jeep Cherokee
    [2] => 1999 Jeep Cherokee
    [3] => 1998 Jeep Cherokee
    [4] => 1997 Jeep Cherokee
    [5] => 1996 Jeep Cherokee
    [6] => 1995 Jeep Cherokee
    [7] => 1998 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [8] => 1997 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [9] => 1996 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [10] => 1995 Jeep Grand Cherokee
    [11] => 2012 Jeep Liberty
    [12] => 2011 Jeep Liberty
    [13] => 2010 Jeep Liberty
    [14] => 2009 Jeep Liberty
    [15] => 2008 Jeep Liberty
    [16] => 2007 Jeep Liberty
    [17] => 2006 Jeep Liberty
    [18] => 2005 Jeep Liberty
    [19] => 2004 Jeep Liberty
    [20] => 2003 Jeep Liberty
    [21] => 2002 Jeep Liberty
    [22] => 2006 Jeep Wrangler
    [23] => 2005 Jeep Wrangler
    [24] => 2004 Jeep Wrangler
    [25] => 2003 Jeep Wrangler
    [26] => 2002 Jeep Wrangler
    [27] => 2001 Jeep Wrangler
    [28] => 2000 Jeep Wrangler
    [29] => 1999 Jeep Wrangler
    [30] => 1998 Jeep Wrangler
    [31] => 1997 Jeep Wrangler
    [32] => 1995 Jeep Wrangler
)
```

The trick is to build this first:

```
Array
(
    [Jeep Cherokee] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2001
            [1] => 2000
            [2] => 1999
            [3] => 1998
            [4] => 1997
            [5] => 1996
            [6] => 1995
        )

    [Jeep Grand Cherokee] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1998
            [1] => 1997
            [2] => 1996
            [3] => 1995
        )

    [Jeep Liberty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012
            [1] => 2011
            [2] => 2010
            [3] => 2009
            [4] => 2008
            [5] => 2007
            [6] => 2006
            [7] => 2005
            [8] => 2004
            [9] => 2003
            [10] => 2002
        )

    [Jeep Wrangler] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2006
            [1] => 2005
            [2] => 2004
            [3] => 2003
            [4] => 2002
            [5] => 2001
            [6] => 2000
            [7] => 1999
            [8] => 1998
            [9] => 1997
            [10] => 1995
        )

)
```

Comment: My favorite solution, thank you all! I can use the multi-dimensional array to a greater advantage than the others, so this is my favorite answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not 100% sure this is what you want, but if you want an array sorted first by Engine and second by Year, I might have a somewhat inelegant but working solution for you.

First, create a new associated ($res = array() ), and *another* 2D temporary array for each Engine name (you can go over the whole array to get a list of engine names, save the names you've already seen in $list, and build a temp array each time you encounter a new name). Put all elements of that engine in that array, so you get

```
[0] => 2012 Jeep Liberty
[7] => 2011 Jeep Liberty
[12] => 2010 Jeep Liberty
[15] => 2009 Jeep Liberty
[18] => 2008 Jeep Liberty
[22] => 2007 Jeep Liberty
[26] => 2006 Jeep Liberty
[44] => 2005 Jeep Liberty
[60] => 2004 Jeep Liberty
[73] => 2003 Jeep Liberty
[86] => 2002 Jeep Liberty
```

as $tempArray['Jeep Liberty'], for example (if Jeep Liberty was the first name you chose, since it had the highest year). Notice it is already sorted by year.

Now, remember $list from earlier, that has all names stored in their appearance order?

```
foreach($list as $value)
  foreach(tempArray[value] as $key => $value2)
    $res += array($key=>$value2.$value);
```

In the end, $res will be of the form

```
[0] => 2012 Jeep Liberty
[7] => 2011 Jeep Liberty
[12] => 2010 Jeep Liberty
[15] => 2009 Jeep Liberty
[18] => 2008 Jeep Liberty
[22] => 2007 Jeep Liberty
[26] => 2006 Jeep Liberty
[44] => 2005 Jeep Liberty
[60] => 2004 Jeep Liberty
[73] => 2003 Jeep Liberty
[86] => 2002 Jeep Liberty
[33] => 2006 Jeep Wrangler
[51] => 2005 Jeep Wrangler
[64] => 2004 Jeep Wrangler
[77] => 2003 Jeep Wrangler
[92] => 2002 Jeep Wrangler
[102] => 2001 Jeep Wrangler 
[114] => 2000 Jeep Wrangler
[125] => 1999 Jeep Wrangler
[149] => 1998 Jeep Wrangler
[169] => 1997 Jeep Wrangler
[203] => 1995 Jeep Wrangler
[96] => 2001 Jeep Cherokee
[106] => 2000 Jeep Cherokee
[117] => 1999 Jeep Cherokee
[128] => 1998 Jeep Cherokee
[152] => 1997 Jeep Cherokee
[173] => 1996 Jeep Cherokee
[186] => 1995 Jeep Cherokee
[136] => 1998 Jeep Grand Cherokee
[159] => 1997 Jeep Grand Cherokee
[181] => 1996 Jeep Grand Cherokee
[193] => 1995 Jeep Grand Cherokee
```

Just as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you looking for:

```
    <?php
    $data[0] = '2012 Jeep Liberty';
    $data[7] = '2011 Jeep Liberty';
    $data[12] = '2010 Jeep Liberty';
    $data[15] = '2009 Jeep Liberty';
    $data[18] = '2008 Jeep Liberty';
    $data[22] = '2007 Jeep Liberty';
    $data[26] = '2006 Jeep Liberty';
    $data[44] = '2005 Jeep Liberty';
    $data[60] = '2004 Jeep Liberty';
    $data[73] = '2003 Jeep Liberty';
    $data[86] = '2002 Jeep Liberty';
    $data[33] = '2006 Jeep Wrangler';
    $data[51] = '2005 Jeep Wrangler';
    $data[64] = '2004 Jeep Wrangler';
    $data[77] = '2003 Jeep Wrangler';
    $data[92] = '2002 Jeep Wrangler';
    $data[102] = '2001 Jeep Wrangler ';
    $data[114] = '2000 Jeep Wrangler';
    $data[125] = '1999 Jeep Wrangler';
    $data[149] = '1998 Jeep Wrangler';
    $data[169] = '1997 Jeep Wrangler';
    $data[203] = '1995 Jeep Wrangler';
    $data[96] = '2001 Jeep Cherokee';
    $data[106] = '2000 Jeep Cherokee';
    $data[117] = '1999 Jeep Cherokee';
    $data[128] = '1998 Jeep Cherokee';
    $data[152] = '1997 Jeep Cherokee';
    $data[173] = '1996 Jeep Cherokee';
    $data[186] = '1995 Jeep Cherokee';
    $data[136] = '1998 Jeep Grand Cherokee';
    $data[159] = '1997 Jeep Grand Cherokee';
    $data[181] = '1996 Jeep Grand Cherokee';
    $data[193] = '1995 Jeep Grand Cherokee';


    function my_cmp($value_1, $value_2)
    {
        $str_1_parts = explode(' ', $value_1);
        $str_2_parts = explode(' ', $value_2);
        $year_1 = (int)$str_1_parts[0];
        $year_2 = (int)$str_2_parts[0];
        if( $year_1 > $year_2 ) return 1;
        if( $year_1 < $year_2 ) return -1;

        unset( $str_1_parts[0] );
        unset( $str_2_parts[0] );
        return strcasecmp( implode(' ', $str_1_parts) , implode(' ', $str_2_parts));
    }
    usort($data,'my_cmp');

    print_r( $data );
```